# How can I add a fragment from within a viewpager that covers the viewpager tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmenttransaction

Currently I have a viewpager setup according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Within the first fragment tab I have setup a recycler view that contains a list of cardviews. Within each cardview I have a button which should open a new fragment. I would like this new fragment to overlap the action bar tabs (something similiar to how facebook comments work when you click the comment button). I am not sure how to get it working. I created an extra framelayout and relative layout above my viewpager hoping that it would overlap, however this doesn't seem to work. How can I have my new fragment cover the action bar tabs as well? I am not asking how to replace the current viewpager fragment if that makes sense.

I filled the new fragment with a red background, the result after envoking the onclick listener is shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJSv2.png

In my onclick listener I have:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, commentFragment,"comment_fragment_tag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

My main activity layout that contains the viewpager:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_activity">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. hope it works

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, commentFragment,"comment_fragment_tag");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

or

```
            Fragment fr = new FragmentTwo() ;
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fr);
            ft.commit();
```

hear fr is the new fragment that would be replaced

Comment: That does not cover the viewpager tabs. The result is pretty much exactly the same as what I showed in my screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/vSXxd.png. I would like to launch a new fragment within the existing viewpager fragment which covers the navigation tabs.

Comment: what do you want ? if you click top rated then open a new fragment, or click movies then open another fragment ... is it ??

Comment: I want to open another fragment that is not a viewpager tab. So say you added a button in the middle of your Games fragment. I'd like that button to launch a completely separate fragment (not any of the viewpager ones).  Something like what the facebook app does when you comment on a post.

Comment: using replace or add seems to have the same effect. I guess one solution is to call actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD) but that means much more work. I don't really see any other way to overlay it with fragmenttractions.